# Set rtsp_flags to listen ffmpeg in c code

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to create a client client server application to stream and then receive video using rtsp using ffmpeg libraries. I am done with the client part which is streaming the video and i can receive the video on ffplay using following command

```
ffplay -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://127.0.0.1:8556/live.sdp
```

My problem is that i want receive the video in a c code and i need to set rtsp_flags option in it. Can anyone plz help?? 
P.S. i cannot use ffserver because i am working on windows and ffserver is not available for windows as far as i knw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the option when opening the stream:

```
AVDictionary *d = NULL;           // "create" an empty dictionary
av_dict_set(&d, "rtsp_flags", "listen", 0); // add an entry

//open rtsp
if ( avformat_open_input( &ifcx, sFileInput, NULL, &d) != 0 ) {
   printf( "ERROR: Cannot open input file\n" );
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```